# fft: fitting binned data

Tags: fft, curve-fitting

I want to fit a curve to data obtained from an FFT. While working on this, I remembered that an FFT gives binned data, and therefore I wondered if I should treat this differently with curve-fitting.

If the bins are narrow compared to the structure, I think it should not be necessary to treat the data differently, but for me that is not the case.

I expect the right way to fit binned data is by minimizing not the difference between values of the bin and fit, but between bin area and the area beneath the fitted curve, for each bin, such that the energy in each bin matches the energy in the range of the bin as signified by the curve.

So my question is: am I thinking correctly about this? If not, how should I go about it?

Also, when looking around for information about this subject, I encountered the "Maximum log likelihood" for example, but did not find enough information about it to understand if and how it applied to my situation.

PS: I have no clue if this is the right site for this question, please let me know if there is a better place.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Show us what you have tried so far. It would particularly help to see a code example producing your fft spectrum, and an example of the curve you want to fit it to. See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Since the question is still at the theoretical stage it's probably better off on http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't think an example would help, because it is a theoretical question: not "how can I achieve this", but "which method give the correct answer". dsp, of course, how have I overlooked that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using maximum log likelihood estimation. This is a method that finds the set of parameters that is most likely to have yielded the measured data - the technique originates in statistics.

I have finally found an understandable source for how to apply this to binned data. Sadly I cannot enter formulas here, so I refer to that source for a full explanation: slide 4 of [this slide show](http://statistics.roma2.infn.it/~vitale/rep/likelihood_canadas.pdf).

**EDIT:**
For noisier signals this method did not seem to work very well. A method that was a bit more robust is a least squares fit, where the difference between the area is minimized, as suggested in the question.

I have not found any literature to defend this method, but it is similar to what happens in the maximum log likelihood estimation, and yields very similar results for noiseless test cases.

Answer (score 0):

For an unwindowed FFT, the correct interpolation between bins is by using a Sinc (sin(x)/x) or periodic Sinc (Dirichlet) interpolation kernel.  For an FFT of samples of a band-limited signal, thus will reconstruct the continuous spectrum.

Comment: I am not looking for an interpolation, but for a fit of the actual peak shape.

Comment: The actual spectrum peak shape, given the information available from the data fed to the FFT, will be produced by Sinc reconstruction.

Comment: I have trouble expressing what I mean here, but let me try: that can't be true, because for example if I measure a gaussian laser pulse, the spectrum should be gaussian, not a sinc. So the sinc behavior must be an 'artifact' of the DFT or the discretization. Fitting a sinc because that matches the effects of the DFT makes no sense from a physical perspective. From a physical perspective you want to fit a function describing the expected spectral shape.

Comment: Sinc kernel reconstruction can reproduce arbitrary band-limited input signal waveform shapes.  That's because interpolation is different from estimating the best-fit single Sinc.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and effective way of interpolating the spectrum (from an FFT) is to use zero-padding. It works both with and without windowing prior to the FFT.

1. Take your input vector of length N and extend it to length M*N, where M is an integer
2. Set all values beyond the original N values to zeros
3. Perform an FFT of length (N*M)
4. Calculate the magnitude of the ouput bins

What you get is the interpolated spectrum.

Best regards,
Jens

Comment: This interpolates the spectrum with a sinc function, but does not give any additional information. My goal is to find the precise position of the peak - interpolation will not help for this.

Comment: There is no addition information to give.  A Sinc reconstruction uses all the information available from the samples given the FFT (assuming they are from a band-limited signal).

Comment: @Ale If you want to dertermine the frequency of a sine in additive white gaussian noise, then I suggest you look up methods like Pisarenko and AR. If it's something else, then please try to explain your problem again.

Comment: @Jens: I will certainly look those up. However, my signal is not a perfect sinoid, but the output of a physical process (stimulated Cherenkov radiation), and I am trying to find not only the central frequency, but also lineshape and the bandwidth. Separate from this application I was also just interested in the implications of having binned data for fitting.

Comment: @Ale If you're looking at a random process (which I think is the case with Cherenkov radiation) your signal is essentially noisy and so is the output from the FFT. The first step would be to average a lot of (power) spectra to get the noise part reduced to a reasonable level. You're probably already doing this. As a next step I suggest you look at an MLE method to estimate the parameters in the distribution you want to characterize.